# .pgpass file does not set default username to connect as

Tags: debian, postgresql

(Debian 8)

My .pgpass file is at my home folder (admin)

I and using the right format as indicated in the documentation

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

The same fields I put there work well when put explicitly into the `psql` command line. (of course I have to enter the password manually).

However, running psql by itself gives our an error:

```
psql: FATAL: role "admin" does not exist
```

Note that my postgres username is NOT "admin", which is my debian username.

What am I doing wrong? my goal is to get access to `psql` without having to use an elaborate command line including host/port/username/database

Answer (score 6):

`psql` defaults to using your current unix username when connecting, unless you specify something different.

If you want a different default you can set the `PGUSER` environment variable.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17632278/398670

`.pgpass` is what `psql` looks up to find out the password for a given host, username, port, etc combo. It doesn't specify what connection to use, only the password to use for a given connection.

You can use env vars, a sevice file, and/or shell aliases to specify connection defaults.